# error: ‘struct tty_driver’ has no member named ‘write’

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am new to kernel module programming and got some problem while compiling some old kernel code. I am getting following error messages,

```
 error: ‘struct tty_driver’ has no member named ‘write’
            ((my_tty->driver)->write) (my_tty,0,str,strlen(str));
```

I checked the `tty_driver.h` file, there `write` is defined. So, Whats going on? How can I access in version `3.13.0-24`?

My code is here:

```
void print_string(char *str)
{
      struct tty_struct *my_tty;
      my_tty = get_current_tty();

      if (my_tty != NULL)
      {
             (*(my_tty->driver)->write)(my_tty, 0, str, strlen(str));
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The [linux kernel source for 3.13](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tty_driver.h?v=3.13#L254) indicates that write is defined, so you have some other version of `tty_driver.h` other than the one for the kernel.

Comment: Newer kernels hide the operations function pointers in an `ops` member structure in `tty_driver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` is indeed defined, but not as members of `tty_driver`. It is defined as members of `tty_operations`, and `tty_driver` has a member `ops`, a pointer to a `const tty_operations`.

So, I used `my_driver->ops->write` instead of `my_driver->driver->write`.